# What exactly happens when we disable history in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, video, streaming, video.js, clappr

I have a problem with live video streams in the system I am developing that happens only in Firefox and only in normal mode.
The player correctly loads the stream, but after a few seconds can't continue to load and just keeps trying and trying forever.

This doesn't happen in Chrome, nor if I load the page in Private Mode, nor with normal videos. Just with live streams, just in Firefox, just in normal mode.
This happens both in local development (home, remote connection) and in the corporative cloud.

It's an Angular 8/NodeJs system and the player I use is [Clappr](http://clappr.io/). I changed to [Video.js](https://videojs.com/) and the problem continued.
The stream is coming from a load balancer with 6 children servers, each one with an apache server who have a proxy to an icecast server that originates the stream.

```
[load balancer] < [6 child servers with apache server proxy] > [icecast server]
```

I work for a very large company that has an IPS system installed. It was the first thing I thought. But the IPS team could not find any blocked traffic. Also if it was that, why would the traffic not be blocked in private mode?

So I thought about trying to pinpoint what the exact configuration is different in private mode that does the trick and I figured out that disabling all history (not only navigation and downloads or forms) makes it work too.

Does anyone knows what exactly happens when the navigation history is disabled? Besides not saving history, does it have an impact on something else? Some type of cache, network or something like that? Anyone has any idea about how to make stream work without disabling history? I can't ask my users to disable history just to use my system.

**EDIT**

One thing that may be relevant to the issue is that in Firefox it doesn't show LIVE label when the transmission starts. It shows a negative number. Maybe this could create some problem with the history.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find the information on what exactly happens when we disable history in Firefox, but I could solve the problem of playing the stream in Firefox, so I won't accept this answer, but leave it here for future reference in case someone has a similar problem.

I solved it by adding `?nocache=<random integer of length 10>` to the video url. Please notice that if you already have some parameter in your url, you can't have 2 `?` characters in your url and have to mix parameters correctly.